# gnome display icons

Tags: command-line, gnome, dconf, gsettings

I am executing the following instruction:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

I'd like to know what changes are made in the file system by this instruction?

Please explain in which file this instruction sets some variable to `value=true`, so that the desktop icons are getting visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are stored in `~/.config/dconf/user` but this is a binary and not human readable so I don't know how you would edit it.

You can view it with

`xxd ~/.config/dconf/user`

[Source0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/where-does-gsettings-store-its-files)

[Source1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/282215/how-to-view-a-binary-file)

As requested here is a .desktop file that will run `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` on boot

Open a new document in a text editor and paste this in

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec= gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
X-Gnome-Auto-Start=True
Name[en_GB]=icons.desktop
```

Save it as `icons.desktop` and make it executable by right click or

```
chmod +x path/to/icons.desktop
```

Now double click `icons.desktop` to confirm it works.

Once you are happy it works move it to `~/.config/autostart`, if it does not exist, make it

```
mkdir ~/.config/autostart
```

Now when you reboot, this will run and activate the icons, if they are already active, it will just do nothing.

Comment: I am actually creating my own ubuntu OS where I have installed gnome with lightdm. But when I test the OS image, the desktop ikons are not appearing until I execute "gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true".

Comment: Why not add a script that turns them on at boot? `#/bin/bash gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true` and run at start up. IDK what to tell you about the ISO, I don't have enough information.

Comment: How to add shell script to run at start up ?

Comment: Take your pick from these options http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up It is not an elegant solution so do feel free to hold out for a better answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
Is there any shortcut, instead of writing a script just for 

"gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true"

we can execute it in .desktop as mentioned in this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up

Can we write "Exec= gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true" ??

Comment: Yes you can, I just tested it and it turned the icons on without a script, just a .desktop.

Comment: Can you please write the answer ? I mean what you have executed ? and in where did you added it ?

Comment: Done.... @techy

Comment: To add to Mark's answer: `gsettings` is the `cli` frontend to `dconf`, which is the low-level editor to the `dconf` database. As Mark mentioned, the settings are stored in the `dconf` database, which is in binary format.